# gmail is modifying header(Message-ID) of incoming mails

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, dkim

I sent a mail from my smtp server to gmail.
The message-id that I got is:
Message-ID: SMTPIN_ADDED_BROKEN@mx.google.com>
         X-Google-Original-Message-ID:

Gmail appended extra parts in Message-id.

All I got on google that it can be an authentication issue.But source of mail shows:
**SPF:PASS**

But DKIM is not present in the source.
Do we require DKIM to be necessarily present in the mail's source??
What can I do to prevent header from being modified?

Answer (score 5):

the msesage ID will be modified only if it does not obey RFC standard. so send mail with correct message id format

Comment: I got the same error and i really can't get my head around why google still adds it. My header looks like `Message-ID: <timestamp-hash@email.com>`, which to my understanding matches the requirements from the RFC.

Comment: Did anyone resolve this, I am still getting this and can't see anything wrong with my Message ID either.

Comment: I solved the issue by surrounding the Message-ID with < and > brackets

Answer (score 4):

After many tries, I finally figured out that you need to add brackets enclosing the Message-Id

<yourid@domain.com>